# Probability of amounts of unsuccessful tries

Tags: probability

Let's we have some special $1,000$ edge dice, and with it chances to win are $1$ in $1000$.

What is probability that someone even after $5,000$ tries still never have won a single time?

How to calculate question like this for general numbers?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of 'winning' on a given throw is $p = \frac{1}{1000}$. Therefore the probability of not winning on any given throw is $q = 1-p = \frac{999}{1000}$. So if you were to throw the dice $5000$ times and not win any single time you must have failed 5000 times, i.e. $$q^{5000} = \left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{5000}$$

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can obtain $\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{5000}$ by typing `$\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{5000}$`.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the tip! I've adited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In situations with a small probability of success and a large number of trials, the Poisson distribution provides a good approximation.  Here the expected number of successes is
$$\lambda = 5000 \cdot \frac{1}{1000} = 5$$
and the probability of having zero successes is, by the Poisson distribution,
$$e^{-\lambda} \approx 0.0067$$